# not able to get choice group target id to set values dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, office-ui-fabric

This is my Choice Group element

```
 <ChoiceGroup defaultSelectedKey="No"
  options={[{ key: 'Yes', text: 'Yes' },{ key: 'No', text: 'No' }]}
  onChange={this._onChange}
  id={'ChoiceGroup1'}
  name={this.state.currentUser} />
```

and my onChange function

```
public _onChange=(ev, option: IChoiceGroupOption)=> {
console.log(ev,option); }
```

but i am not able get **target.id** value. The target shows null but in case of **Textfield** i am able to get name and target of component

Comment: Can you share the relevant `ChoiceGroup` component code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually pass the selected item's id to the _onChange function.

Based on the props and the used case, i assume your **ChoiceGroup** component maps through the "options" prop and renders another component. If that's the case, you can tweak it a little bit to make it pass the clicked item up to the parent component (so you can decide what to do with it).

So in your ChoiceGroup component add

```
{options.map(option =>
<ChoiceGroupOption
  onClick={e => onItemSelected(option)}
/>}

 <ChoiceGroup defaultSelectedKey="No"
   options={[{ key: 'Yes', text: 'Yes' },{ key: 'No', text: 'No' }]}
   onItemSelected={item => this._onChange(e, item.id)}
   id={'ChoiceGroup1'}
   name={this.state.currentUser} />
```

Then in the event handler put this:

```
public _onChange = (ev, selectedId)=> {
    console.log('ID: ', selectedId);
}
```

Comment: What is `selectedId` in this code? My guess is that the `ChoiceGroup` component passes the selected option to the handler, so this solution looks like it drops that and passes an undefined value to the `this._onChange` handler.

Comment: I assume he has a map somewhere that displays the items, in which case the id can be easily passed as an argument to the function.
ChoiceGroup is surely a custom component as there is no such html tag as this.

Comment: That's quite an assumption and still doesn't explain where `selectedId` comes from.

Comment: @DrewReese i edited my answer to explain further.